# Why people attach the original exception type name to the exception object

Tags: c++, boost

Why some people attach the original exception type name to the exception object derived from boost::exception using the `operator<<`? I mean smth like this:

```
#define MY_THROW(Ex) \
throw Ex << base_exception::original_type_info(typeid((Ex)).name())
```

I think that typeid in catch should give the same result. Am I right? What the purpose of such adding?